# How can I read out a date cell in Excel using a Date format in Java

Tags: java, excel, date

I am writing a program that can read out an Excel file. I have a couple of date values in there and I would like to properly read them out.

For now I am using:

```
Date UKDate = null;

switch (counter) {
case 1:
       UKDate= cell.getDateCellValue();
       break;
```

Unforuntately I will have to transfer the value into my database. The output my Java Console gives is:

```
Sun Jan 21 00:00:00 CET 2007
```

I would like to simply make it "dd/MM/yyyy" but I don't know how to do that.

I tried doing it with a String first. So..:

```
case 1:
       UKDate= cell.getStringCellValue();
       break;
```

Then I get the error saying that the program can't read a STRING value from a NUMERIC cell.

I hope anyone would like to help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

**Use `SimpleDateFormat` to format the Date output**

Example :

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
System.out.println(format.format(UKDate));
```

*By the way every database has date type field, you could just save the `UKDate` directly if you define the datatype as date*

If you want to save it to mysql you need to convert it to `java.sql.Date`

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(UKDate.getTime());
```

Comment: I know every database has a date datatype, but when I try to put Sun 
    Jan 21 00:00:00 CET 2007
into my database the field will just see it as 00:00:00.

Comment: Or you could just use the output of `format.format(UKDate)`